# QT ninja.build error (Too many input files specified: '/Appname/main.qml' '/Users/batman/Appname/main.qml')

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator

After updating QT-Creator my project won't compile anymore.
I backtraced it into ninja.build file where it tries to execute the following command:

```
/Users/batman/Qt/6.6.1/macos/./libexec/qmlcachegen --bare --resource-path / /Appname/main.qml -I :/ -I /Users/batman/build-Appname-Qt_6_6_1_for_macOS-Debug -I /Users/batman/Qt/6.6.1/macos/./qml -i /Users/batman/build-Appname-Qt_6_6_1_for_macOS-Debug/Appname/qmldir --resource /Users/batman/build-Appname-Qt_6_6_1_for_macOS-Debug/.rcc/qmake_Appname.qrc --resource /Users/batman/build-Appname-Qt_6_6_1_for_macOS-Debug/.rcc/Appname_raw_qml_0.qrc -o /Users/batman/build-Appname-Qt_6_6_1_for_macOS-Debug/.rcc/qmlcache/Appname_main_qml.cpp /Users/batman/Appname/main.qml
```

Now the source of the error (*Too many input files specified: '/Appname/main.qml' '/Users/batman/Appname/main.qml'*) seems to be the following argument in the above command:

```
--resource-path / /Appname/main.qml
```

Changing the arguments to

```
--resource-path / --resource-path /Appname/main.qml
```

Would successfully generate the file passed to the "-o" argument when running from the terminal.

So my question is: How/where is that ninja.build file generated and how can I change the generated command line?

Thanks!!